# How to load custom php file in Wordpress themes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've just created a website using wordpress and a custom theme for it. This is my theme directory

```
/themes/customtheme/
 -index.php
 -header.php
 -footer.php
 -blog.php
 ....
```

The `index.php` includes *header*,*footer*,information to shown on my website, and a link to my blog page.

Blog file will looks same as normal blog site.

May i know how to write a hyperlink(a href) in `index.php` under theme directory so that it can prompt to the `blog.php` when click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your question you need to create a new page template using your `blog.php` file. Just add the following code at the beginning of the file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Blog Page
*/
```

And then create in the backed a new page and associate it to the newly created template.

Read more about page templates [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates).

Comment: may i know how to write a link to open this page?? a href=??

Comment: You would have to write it like <a href="[the-permalink]">Blog</a> where [the-permalink] is the permalink identifying your newly created page.