# Wordress - How to work with non wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I'm new to wordpress, and I want to know if it is possible to put a theme bought on shapedtheme.com for example on an existing wordpress.

And if so, how to do it. I don't know where to put the code of the theme. I saw the wordpress page builder with text, but I see tags with `[]` and not `<>`.

I saw on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250885/how-to-load-custom-php-file-in-wordpress-themes?rq=1) thread that pages can be linked to php files. I don't see how.

I have full access to the hosting service's filesystem and can see all wordpress files.

I would also like to transpose the theme header and footer and if possible, use the theme cards to adapt to blog articles written in wordpress.

How can I do this ?

I searched for tutorials on google or related threads on SO with no luck.

Any ressource would be appreciated.

Thanks to anyone who will take the time to read/answer this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use a non-WordPress theme in a WordPress installation since WordPress will look for specific templates and pass certain objects to the template to be displayed.

You could adapt it to work with WordPress, though. Here's the [theming guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) to get you started.

But you'll probably be able to find a WordPress-ready theme with the features you want. This is the WordPress theme directory link for [themes using bootstrap](https://wordpress.org/themes/search/bootstrap/).

Unless you go for a *from-scratch* development of a pure php theme, and you need some level of theme customization I'd strongly suggest looking into [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), as it'll allow you to update the base theme minimizing the changes you'd have to do to yours.

The `[ ]` syntax you mention are [`shortcodes`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), small, safe php functions that can be executed by inserting them in the editor, templates, etc, and provide kind of an api that exposes WordPress or plugins functionality.

And regarding your link, OP already has a WordPress theme, but is looking for a way of using a different, specialized template on specific pages. This template still has to follow to certain WordPress conventions.

Comment: Is it possible to put a bootstrap theme on a website, then to redirect on a wordpress blog with the header and footer of this bootstrap theme ?

Comment: @PierrickMartellière There are lots of bootstrap themes for WP out there. A quick search gave me [this](https://colorlib.com/wp/free-bootstrap-wordpress-themes/). It's possible but you'll still have to do some leg work to pass the menus, images, etc. Not sure is worth it. Edited my answer and addressed your question about `[]`